# Unable to load bigquery data in local spark (on my mac) using pyspark

Tags: google-bigquery, pyspark

I am getting below error after executing below code. Am I missing something in the installation? I am using spark installed on my local mac and so I am checking to see if I need to install additional libraries for below code to work and load data from bigquery.

> ```py
> Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-8-9d6701949cac> in <module>()
>      13     "com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat",
>      14     "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable", "com.google.gson.JsonObject",
> ---> 15     conf=conf).map(lambda k: json.loads(k[1])).map(lambda x: (x["word"],
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
> : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonObject
> ```

```py
import json
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()

hadoopConf=sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.get("fs.gs.system.bucket")

conf = {"mapred.bq.project.id": "<project_id>", "mapred.bq.gcs.bucket": "<bucket>",
    "mapred.bq.input.project.id": "publicdata", 
    "mapred.bq.input.dataset.id":"samples", 
    "mapred.bq.input.table.id": "shakespeare"  }

tableData = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    "com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat",
    "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable", "com.google.gson.JsonObject", 
    conf=conf).map(lambda k: json.loads(k[1])).map(lambda x: (x["word"],
    int(x["word_count"]))).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)

print tableData.take(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonObject" seems to hint that a library is missing.

Please try adding the gson jar to your path: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.google.code.gson|gson|2.6.1|jar

Comment: felipe thanks! i am getting another error now - 

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat

Is it again a missing jar issue?

Comment: yes, you are missing the BigQuery connector now: https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bigquery-connector

Comment: yes thanks i downloaded that! getting another error as below. do you know how should i pass bigquery account credentials in my code? i am running the attached code (in my main question).

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token from metadata server at: http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token

Comment: Authentication? Please see the docs at https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/setting-up-a-hadoop-cluster

Comment: Actually i have spark installed locally and i am trying to get bigquery data into spark. But its not clear how should i pass my bigquery credentials (access key) in the code?

Comment: Try a new question, someone else might have a better answer than mine. Tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting something buried in the [connector](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bigquery-connector) link in Felipe's response: the bq connector used to be included by default in Cloud Dataproc, but was dropped starting at v 1.3. The link shows you three ways to get it back.